# Using Queue Data Structure to solve problem

Tags: java

My code involves me to calculate the amount of time required for a person in a certain position in a queue to buy burgers with the index of the burgers array showing an integer of the amount of burgers a person ordered. Each time a person at the head buys a burger they are taken to the tail and have one burger removed and 1 time value added. I have to find the amount of time it takes for the person at what position I inputted to find the time to buy all of their burgers.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Queue;

public class A4Q2 {
    

    public int calcTimeReqToBuyBurgers(int[] burgers, int p)
    {
        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        q.addAll(burgers);

        int time = 0;
        int i = 0;

        numBurg = burgers[p];

        while(numBurg > 0) {
            int x = q.remove();
            x--;
            if(x != 0) {
                q.add(x);
            }
            time +=1;

            

        }

        
      
        return time;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A4Q2 ex = new A4Q2();
        

    }
}
```

I do not know where to go from here or if I am even doing this right. I know my question might look a little messy but I am still new to this website. Can someone help me?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: I think somewhere you need to decrement the numBurg  otherwise the while loop will go infinite(as long as >0).
Supposing x as your current burger check if is equal to numBurg and make
time ++;
q.add(x --);
numBurg -- ;

Comment: @spring00  Ok. But i am still to believe that while the position we are calculating for is placed at the tail of the queue, i still have to compute the time for the next person in the head and on and on until person p goes to zero? How would I do that?

Comment: It would be great if you could put a bit more love and effort into the formatting of your question. There is superfluous space in the code. Not all code is inside the code formatting. As mentioned, improve the title.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use queue for this, and also in your solution it seems that you are not reducing numBurg(which makes the queue run infinitely) and also you need to keep track of index of numBurg. Then I guess it would work. Below is my solution

```
int time = 0;
int p_value = burgers[p];
for(int i=0;i<burgers.length;i++){
  if(burgers[p] > p_value) time+=p_value;
  else time+=burgers[p];
  if(i == p) p_value-=1;
}
return time;
```

Explanation: you need to reduce burgers[p] value from all the elements in array until you reach p but after that you can stop so the prior elements will have only p-1 reduced in them as we can stop after we reach p. and also if someone needs less burgers they will only participate until they reach 0. This would be O(n) with no extra space solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public int calcTimeReqToBuyBurgers(int[] burgers, int p)
   {
 Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();

   for (int burger : burgers){
      q.add(burger);}
   int time = 0;
   int i = 0;

int numBurg = burgers[p];
while(numBurg > 0) {
    int curr = q.remove();
    if(curr == 1){time  ++;}
    if(curr > 1){
        q.add(curr);
        time ++;
    }
    if(curr == numBurg){
        q.add(curr -- );
        numBurg --;
        time ++;
    }

 }

 return time;
 } 

public static void main(String[] args) {
A4Q2  ex = new A4Q2 ();
int [] burgers= new int [] {3,2,4,1};
int time=ex.calcTimeReqToBuyBurgers(burgers,1);
System.out.println("time "+time);


}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. I will look into this and see how this logic works. I am extremely grateful for all of your help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).